# Django 2.0: Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: django, django-views

So I just added an update view to my detail view. However, when I try to load the page after I add the 'Edit' button below, I am getting a Generic Detail View error. What is going on?

Template Page:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'thing:update' thing_id=thing_id%}" class="btn btn-primary" class>Edit</a></td>
```

urls.py

```
        path('update/<slug:thing_id>/', ThingUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
```

views.py

```
    class ThingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model      = ThingUser
    form_class = ThingUserFormSet
    template_name = "thing/update.html"
```

Traceback

```
File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  189.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  47.                                  % self.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /thing/update/8bv4tyrkyy/
Exception Value: Generic detail view ThingUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Django using `slug` as slug url keyword argument. Since you are using `thing_id` you need to set it in the view using [`slug_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) attribute:

```
class ThingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model      = ThingUser
    form_class = ThingUserFormSet
    template_name = "thing/update.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'thing_id'
```